# How to update cordova-plugin-device in my meteor project?

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

When i run my meteor project, i have this Warning:

> WARNING: Attempting to install plugin cordova-plugin-device@0.3.0, but
>   it should have a minimum version of 1.1.1 to ensure compatibility with
>   the current platform versions. Installing the minimum
>            version for convenience, but you should adjust your dependencies.

And then, I have this error:

> I20160401-19:50:43.017(2)? E/MeteorWebApp(19633):
>   com.meteor.webapp.WebAppException: Skipping downloading new version
>   because the Cordova platform version or plugin versions have changed
>   and are potentially incompatible

How to update cordova-plugin-device plugin ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Meteor project folder .meteor
create a file cordova-plugins and insert the line cordova-plugin-device@1.1.1...
meteor will rebuild with that version

Answer (score 4):

I removed and re-added the Android, in my case, mobile platform:

```
meteor remove-platform android
meteor add-platform android
```

That fixed the error for me.