# meteor android app not running after updating meteor

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, apk

Initially I was using meteor version 1.3 and I was able to run the app on android phone using the following command :

```
sudo -E meteor run android-device --allow-superuser --settings server/settings.json
```

Now I have update the app to version 1.5 and am using the same command to run on android phone but I get the following error

```
You're trying to install apk with a lower versionCode that is already
installed.
Either uninstall an app or increment the versionCode.]
name: 'CordovaError',
message: 'Failed to install apk to device:
```

I uninstalled the previous version of the app I had but still getting the error. Also, the app is running fine on browser (sudo meteor --settings server/settings.json works fine on browser even after updating meteor version) and even on other devices. Just an issue with my device.

As far as I can tell, the problem is with cordova version. But i uninstalled the app from my phone, followed the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36363217/how-to-update-cordova-plugin-device-in-my-meteor-project), but still the error persists.

Any help to resolve the error would be appreciated.

Cheers